# How to define classes and a constructor and how to call them in R / RStudio

Tags: r, class, constructor

I usually work in Java, so classes are usually pretty easy for me to work with. However, I'm learning R in RStudio again and the (S3?) classes are confusing to me.

```
s3 <- list(name = "Kyle", age = 19, blood_Type = "B-")
class(s3) <- "student"
```

^That should define a class called "student" with 3 fields and an instance of that class, I believe. But I don't know how to make a constructor, how to make functions, and then call those functions/constructors with an instance.

Any help or resources on this is appreciated.

Comment: In R, S3 classes don't have "constructors", you likely want [R6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/index.html) for a more-comparable OO experience.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html).